# Equality of $\sigma$-algebras in Blumenthal's 0-1 Law Proof Question

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am studying out of Klenke's probability theory book and I have a question about why two $\sigma$-algebras are equal in the proof of Blumenthal's 0-1 Law.

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\in [0,\infty)}$ be a Brownian motion and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in [0,\infty)}, \mathbb{P})$ the corresponding filtered (adapted) probability space (Let me know also if this language is totally wrong, I am still learning). Blumenthal states that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_0^+=\bigcap_{t>0}\mathcal{F}_t$ is $\mathbb{P}$-trivial.

Now, Klenke's approach is to study the sequence of increments as they tend towards zero. Define the sequence of (independent) random variables $Y^m=(B_{2^{-m}+t}-B_{2^{-m}})_{t\in [0,2^{-m}]}$ (toward the objective of applying Kolomogorov's 0-1 law), which he remarks take values in $C([0,2^{-m}])$. Now, I believe that he is thinking about $C([0,2^{-m}])$ as the metric space with the sup norm topology, so we have
$$\sigma(Y^m; m\geq n)=\sigma(\{(Y^m)^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(g)): g\in C([0,2^{-m}]), \varepsilon>0, m\geq n\}),$$
where
$$B_\varepsilon(g)=\{f\in C([0,2^{-m}]): \sup_{t\in [0,2^{-m}]}\lvert f(t)-g(t)\rvert<\varepsilon\},$$
or possibly some other equivalent characterization of the generated $\sigma$-algebra. But now the step that I don't understand is that we have
$$\mathcal{F}_{2^{-n+1}}=\sigma(Y^m; m\geq n).$$

Any hints about why this might be true? The rest of the proof seems fine once you accept this set equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean $\mathcal{F}_{2^{-n+1}}=\sigma(Y^m; m\geq n)$.

Hint: It is easy to see that each $Y^{m}$ is $\mathcal F_{2^{-n+1}}$ measurable.

For the reverse inclusion use the following:  If $0\leq t \leq 2^{-m+1}$ then $B_t=\lim_{k \to \infty} \{(B_t-B_{t-\frac  1 {2^{k}}})+(B_{t-\frac  1 {2^{k}}}-B_{t-\frac  2 {2^{k}}})+(B_{t-\frac  2 {2^{k}}}-B_{t-\frac  3 {2^{k}}})+\cdots +(B_{t-\frac  {j-1} {2^{k}}}-B_{t-\frac  j {2^{k}}})\}$ where $j=[2^{k}t]$

Comment: Ok awesome, I had a suspicion that it might be some kind of telescoping argument.